# Render a BitmapSource to a DrawingContext without pixel interpolation

Tags: wpf

I have a class derived from `Image`, to which I set the `Source` to a `BitmapSource` and override the `OnRender(DrawingContext dc)` method so I can overlay the image with some info.

What I want to do is to render this `BitmapSource` with no interpolation, so the original image's pixel boundaries are apparent when zoomed into. But I could not find any property of the `DrawingContext` that would allow me to set the interpolation mode for bitmaps.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Set RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode to NearestNeighbor in the Image element.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for the comment! Exactly which object has this property? Or how can I get the RenderOptions object related to this Image / DrawingContext?

Comment: It's an attached property that you would set on the Image.

Comment: Oh, great! I can do it from XAML like this then:  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor".
It works! You can submit that as an answer and I'll accept it. If you don't want to I will post it myself.
Might be useful for someone else.